# Select2 - The jQuery replacement for select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

"parent is highlighted, and child below it. We need same structure
https://github.com/select2/select2/releases

This is the link of jquery plugin.
I had never used before and by downloading the provided source,I got NO idea about how to implement.If anyone Used of knows the exact tutorial or can explain me in brief than please help me out.
Thanks in advance.:-)

Comment: Look at the [plugin website](https://select2.github.io/). It has all the info you need.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [plugin website](https://select2.github.io/).
It has all the info you need.

> Getting started with Select2
>
> In order to use Select2, you must include the JavaScript and CSS file on your website. You can get these files built for you from many different locations.

It even has detailed examples: https://select2.github.io/examples.html